# ClientDataSet records (move once +1 once -1)

Tags: delphi

In the `Jvdbgrid1` `table`, I always have only two `ClientDataSet` records.
When I am on the first record, how to go on the second record and conversely.
When I am on the second record, how to go on the first record.

So (`buttonClick`) once the record is +1 once -1

How to save this in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are on the second record and want to get to the first one, just call

```
ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(-1)
```

When on the first record, to get to the second, call

```
ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(1)
```

But if you want your app to do this automatically, it's easier to use `.Next` and `.Prior`, as in

```
procedure TForm1.ToggleRecord;
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Next;
  if ClientDataSet1.Eof then
    ClientDataset1.Prior;
end;
```

**Update** The cleanest/simplest equivalent to what you do in your answer seems to be

```
procedure TForm1.PlayFile;
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.RecNo));
end;

procedure TForm1.ToggleRecord2;
var
  Distance : Integer;
begin
  if ClientDataSet1.RecNo = 2 then
    Distance := -1
  else
    Distance := 1;

  ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(Distance);

  PlayFile;

  Distance := - Distance;
  ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(Distance);
end;
```

but it is pretty much a matter of taste.  Ymmv ...

Comment: That's what I mean. But,the program should know whether ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(1) or ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(-1)

Comment: I mean something like that:  `if ClientDataSet.RecNo = 1 then  ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(1);  if  ClientDataSet.RecNo = 2 then ClientDataSet1.MoveBy(-1);` Just make more sense written in code

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question. I miss an English word to ask, I try ok? Everything as it is In this code. Only physically do not move to the record, only to play under the procedure, and physically stay on the same record.,It is possible ? 
We are on the first record buttonClick and my procedure will be done from the second record

Comment: There is no physical movement involved.  All that the navigation commands (First, Last, Next, Prior, MoveBy) do is to move the dataset's "logical" cursor, which is effectively a pointer to the dataset's active record.

Comment: Exactly, I mean not to move the logical cursor. If it is on the first record To stay here. And my procedure was played out of the second recordu. Click again on the same buton  does not change place logical cursor. Every one click when we are at first record we assign (play) my procedure from under the second record. .I hope you understand a bit (buton repeat)

Comment: I'm afraid you have lost me completely.  You can only access the data of the active table record, which is what the logical cursor points to.  If you want to "stay" on a record but retrieve data from another record, a way to do that is to place a bookmark on the current record (using GetBookmark), navigate to the other record and do what you want, then return to the one you were on using GotoBookmark/FreeBookmark.  YOu might also take a look at CloneCursor in the online help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I succeeded :)
That's exactly what I meant. Question to you.
You can write this code more sensibly (better)

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if assigned(idictionary) then
  begin

    if ClientDataSet1.RecNo = 1 then
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.Next;
      PlayFile;
      ClientDataSet1.Prior;
    end;

    if ClientDataSet1.RecNo = 2 then
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.Prior;
      PlayFile;
      ClientDataSet1.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```